# Multiple Select in Variables

Tags: javascript, html

**Hello.**

```js
var action = document.getElementById("action").value;
var a = document.getElementById("a").value;
var b = document.getElementById("b").value;
var c = document.getElementById("c").value;
var d = document.getElementById("d").value;
var e = document.getElementById("e").value;
var f = document.getElementById("f").value;
```

```html
<select class="form-control" multiple id="action">
  <option id="a">A</option>
  <option id="b">B</option>
  <option id="c">C</option>
  <option id="d">D</option>
  <option id="e">E</option>
  <option id="f">F</option>
</select>
```

I am trying to have it when I select option A and B for example, those **both** options will be equal to X, and the other will be **empty**.

If option A, B, C is selected:

```
A = "X"
B = "X"
C = "X"
D = ""
E = ""
F = ""
```

Thanks in advance, aye!

Answer (score 0):

In order to do that you'll have to add an `onchange` listener to the `<select>` element so you can run a function when the selected options change.

After that, you could get all the options using `action.options` and you can check if an option is selected using `action.option[N].selected`.

Here is an example:

```js
var action = document.getElementById("action");
action.addEventListener("change", function() { // listen for changes
  var options = Array.from(action.options).reduce((a, o) => { // create an object using the option's value as a key and "X" as value if the option is selected;
    a[o.value] = o.selected ? "X" : "";
    return a; 
  }, {});

  console.log(options);
})
```

```html
<select class="form-control" multiple id="action">
  <option id="a">A</option>
  <option id="b">B</option>
  <option id="c">C</option>
  <option id="d">D</option>
  <option id="e">E</option>
  <option id="f">F</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
var a = document.querySelector('#a');
var b = document.querySelector('#b');
var c = document.querySelector('#c');
var d = document.querySelector('#d');
var e = document.querySelector('#e');
var f = document.querySelector('#f');

a.addEventListener('click',()=>{
a = 'X'; //use this if want to change var a
})

b.addEventListener('click',function(){
b = 'X';
})

c.addEventListener('click',function(){
c = 'X';
})

d.addEventListener('click',function(){
d = 'X';
})

e.addEventListener('click',function(){
e = 'X';
})

f.addEventListener('click',function(){
f = 'X';
})
```

```html
<select class="form-control" multiple id="action">
  <option id="a">A</option>
  <option id="b">B</option>
  <option id="c">C</option>
  <option id="d">D</option>
  <option id="e">E</option>
  <option id="f">F</option>
</select>
```

May be you can use this code.

Comment: Aye, I was trying to do something different, I don't want the text to change to X, but rather have the var a-f change to "X" if I have them selected. If not, have them blank.

Comment: There are many way to try this, but the logic is same.
Glad to hear if it helps you, please accept the answer

Comment: Can you help me achieve this then? I couldn't get it to work, unfortunately.

Comment: TYVM! Value brings back "null" whether it's selected or not (I didn't use the innerHTML), just a = 'X'; after the eventlistener

Comment: Do you possibly know why it brings back null?

Comment: What value you are say ? i think because you replace a value of variable

Answer (score 0):

Found a solution.
First, change all values on the options to "X" (in my case, wanted to set it to X).

```
var values = $('#action').val();
var e = values[4];
var b = values[1];
var ce = values[2];
var d = values[3];
var f = values[5];
var a = values[0];

if (a == undefined){
    a = "";
}

if (b == undefined){
    b = "";
}

if (ce == undefined){
    ce = "";
}

if (d == undefined){
    d = "";
}

if (e == undefined){
    e = "";
}

if (f == undefined){
    f = "";
}
```